# Como dividir uma Lista Proporcionalmente 32%, 32% e 36%

Tags: c#

Eu possuo uma `lista("arquivo txt")` com cerca de 150 valores com três tipos de flores "Iris-setosa", "Iris-versicolor", "Iris-virginica" preciso ler esse arquivo, verificar a quantidade de cada flor nesse arquivo, e após saber a quantidade preciso gerar 3 novas listas divididas proporcionalmente pela quantidade de cada flor no arquivo.

exemplo arquivo:

```
5.7,2.8,4.1,1.3,Iris-versicolor

6.3,3.3,6.0,2.5,Iris-virginica

5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
```

ler o arquivo eu já consegui, o problema é ver quantas tem de cada e dividir em 3 novas lista proporcionalmente pela quantidade de cada flor.

digamos que possua 50 de cada flor, preciso colocar cerca de 17 flores de cada tipo em uma nova lista.

poderiam me ajudar ?

O que possuo até agora

```
namespace Classificadores
{
   class Program
   {       
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Flor> flores = Flor.GetFlores();

        var rnd = new Random();
        var query =
        from i in flores
        let r = rnd.Next()
        orderby r
        select i;

        var shuffledFlores = query.ToList();

        List<Flor> ShuffleFlores1 = new List<Flor>();
        List<Flor> ShuffleFlores2 = new List<Flor>();
        List<Flor> ShuffleFlores3 = new List<Flor>();

        for(int i = 0; i < shuffledFlores.Count; i++)
        {

        }         

        double[] flor = { 6.1, 2.8, 4.7, 1.2 };      

        Console.WriteLine(Flor.Classifier(ShuffleFlores1, flor));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}

public class Flor
{
    public double[] Features;
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Flor(double sepalLenght, double sepalWidth, double petalLenght, double petalWidth, string Nome)
    {
        Features = new double[4];
        Features[0] = sepalLenght;
        Features[1] = sepalWidth;
        Features[2] = petalLenght;
        Features[3] = petalWidth;
        this.Nome = Nome;
    }

    public static double Distance(double[] a, double[] b)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            sum += Math.Pow(a[i] - b[i], 2);
        return Math.Sqrt(sum);
    }

    public static string Classifier(List<Flor> flores, double[] Features)
    {
        double val = 0.0;
        double min = double.MaxValue;
        string label = String.Empty;
        foreach (Flor flor in flores)
        {
            val = Distance(flor.Features, Features);
            if (val < min)
            {
                min = val;
                label = flor.Nome;
            }
        }
        return label;
    }

    public static List<Flor> GetFlores()
    {
        List<Flor> flores = new List<Flor>();
        var colunas = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Flor.txt");

        foreach (string coluna in colunas)
        {
            var linha = coluna.Split(",");
            var flor = new Flor(Convert.ToDouble(linha[0]), Convert.ToDouble(linha[1]), Convert.ToDouble(linha[2]), Convert.ToDouble(linha[3]), linha[4]);
            flores.Add(flor);
        }

        return flores;
    }
}
```

Comment: Para contar cada tipo de flor pode usar [Count (LINQ)](http://www.csharp-examples.net/linq-count/): `int setosa = flores.Count(f => f.Nome == "Iris-setosa");` quanto ao resto ficou difícil de perceber o que quer fazer exactamente...

Comment: se você tem uma `List<Flor>` com 150 elementos, que têm 3 tipos de flor, por exemplo, 50 flores de cada tipo, e quer dividir cada tipo em 3 partes iguais, então você quer ficar com 9 listas? é isso?

Comment: @vik na verdade eu preciso de 3 listas proporcionais, preciso de 33% de cada flor em cada lista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se é isto:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp14
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var flores = GetDummyFlores();

            List<Flor> ShuffleFlores1 = new List<Flor>();
            List<Flor> ShuffleFlores2 = new List<Flor>();
            List<Flor> ShuffleFlores3 = new List<Flor>();

            var allLists = new List<List<Flor>>() { ShuffleFlores1, ShuffleFlores2, ShuffleFlores3 };

            var collection = flores.GroupBy(f => f.Nome);

            foreach (var group in collection)
            {
                var list = group.ToList();

                //ShuffleFlores1.AddRange(list.GetRange(0, list.Count() / 3));
                //list.RemoveRange(0, list.Count() / 3);

                //ShuffleFlores2.AddRange(list.GetRange(0, list.Count() / 2));
                //list.RemoveRange(0, list.Count() / 2);

                //ShuffleFlores3.AddRange(list.GetRange(0, list.Count()));
                //list.RemoveRange(0, list.Count());

                for (int i = 0; i < allLists.Count; i++)
                {
                    int items = list.Count() / (3 - i);
                    allLists[i].AddRange(list.GetRange(0, items));
                    list.RemoveRange(0, items);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static List<Flor> GetDummyFlores()
        {
            var list = new List<Flor>();

            var flores = new string[] { "Iris-versicolor", "Iris-virginica", "Iris-setosa" };

            for (int i = 0; i < flores.Length; i++)
            {
                list.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(50 * i , 50).Select(x => new Flor(flores[i], x)));
            }
            return list;
        }
    }

    class Flor
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public int DummyId { get; set; }

        public Flor(string nome, int dummyId)
        {
            this.Nome = nome;
            this.DummyId = dummyId;
        }

        public Flor() { }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{this.Nome} # {this.DummyId}";
        }
    }
}
```

A parte comentada faz o mesmo que o ciclo `for` seguinte, não necessitando da `var allLists`.

Com 9 flores de cada tipo ficam assim as listas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se quiser as listas baralhadas terá que fazer depois.

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que você possa resolver de duas maneiras.

**Solução 1:** Já sabendo a quantidade de grupos (no caso, você sabe), você pode resolver com um `foreach`:

```
List<Flor> flores = Flor.GetFlores();

var rnd = new Random();
var query =
from i in flores
let r = rnd.Next()
orderby r
select i;

var versicolor = new List<Flor>();
var virginica = new List<Flor>();
var setosa = new List<Flor>();

foreach (var flor in query)
{
    if (flor.Nome == "Iris-versicolor")
    {
        versicolor.Add(flor);
    }
    else if (flor.Nome == "Iris-virginica")
    {
        virginica.Add(flor);
    }
    else if (flor.Nome == "Iris-setosa") //else 
    {
        setosa.Add(flor);
    }
}
```

**Solução 2:** Não sabendo a quantidade de grupos, utilize os métodos de extensão `IEnumerable<T>.GroupBy` e `IEnumerable<T>.ToDictionary` para agrupar em um dicionário de nomes:

List flores = Flor.GetFlores();

```
var rnd = new Random();
var query =
from i in flores
let r = rnd.Next()
orderby r
select i;

Dictionary<string, List<Flor>> floresPorNome = query.GroupBy(f => f.Nome).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```